# Use two images in Xamarin Forms Android Splash Screen

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am completely new to Xamarin Forms Cross Platform Development. I wan to implement Whatsapp like Splash Screen. See below[image]

With my existing code I am not able to use two different images in a splash screen. Followed the normal splash screen tutorials and able to generate simple splash with single image.
here piece of code from my Splash.XMl (theme file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <color android:color="@color/primary"></color>
  </item>

  <item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/Logo" android:gravity="center" android:tileMode="disabled"></bitmap>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ack" android:gravity="bottom" android:tileMode="disabled"></bitmap>

  </item>


</layer-list>
```

I used two different `<item></item>`but no success. Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you want to have 2 different images in one screen, or have 2 different screens, like you have shown in the 2 pictures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you try with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
           <color android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
          android:src="@drawable/xamarin_small"
          android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="40dp">
        <bitmap
          android:src="@drawable/microsoft"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

With the code above I am able to display the two images as part of the background for the launcher.

[image]

Hope this helps.-

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have 2 images in one splash screen, then follow @pinedax' answer. However, if you'd like to have 2 totally different splash screens, then it is a separate question. The 2 screenshots that you have provided are for the 2 themes - light & dark. Starting from Android 10 (API level 29) Google has release dark mode for smartphones. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme)

So what you will need is to have 2 separate splash screen xmls and let the system load them according to the phone's preferred theme.
Inside the Resources/drawable folder, you can create 2 files:

`splash_screen.xml`:

```xml
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
<item
        android:width="215dp"
        android:height="105dp"
        android:gravity="center">
    <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/your_dark_icon_here"
            android:gravity="fill"/>
</item>
```

`splash_screen_night.xml`

```xml
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>
    <item
            android:width="215dp"
            android:height="105dp"
            android:gravity="center">
        <bitmap
                android:src="@drawable/your_light_icon_here"
                android:gravity="fill"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Take a look at the colors and the images - the first xml is with **white** background & **dark** logo and the second xml is the one for the dark mode - **black** background with **light** logo.

After that you will need to create a new folder inside your Resources - `values-night`. 
There, you will have one more `styles.xml` file. Now you will have 2 `styles.xml` files - one in **Resources/values** and one one **Resources/values-night**

*NB: Mind the casing, since these folders & files are case-sensitive!*

Inside **Resources/values/styles.xml** you can set the launch theme like so:

```xml
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="MainTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
</style>
```

Inside **Resources/values-night/styles.xml** you can set the launch theme like so:

@drawable/splash_screen_night

The last thing to do is to set the splash screen in our Activity.

```c#
[Activity(Label = "DarkModeSplashScreen", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/LaunchTheme", LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```

For detailed steps & also how to implement it on iOS you can follow this great tutorial: [Xamarin: Creating a Dark Mode Splash Screen](https://codetraveler.io/2019/10/11/creating-a-dark-mode-splash-screen/)